# Split a string of an array with a lambda stream using linq

Tags: c#, .net

Well I have this array:

```
string[] fullNames = new string[] { 
 "Bryan Scott", "Bradley Scott", "Ava Smith", "Olivia Williams"
};
```

And I want to splitt the firstname and the lastname. After I did this I'd like to print first the Lastname with every char in upper case and on the second position I'd like to print the firstname with no upper case.

This is what I already got.

```
fullNames.Where(x => x.Contains(" "))
```

I'd like to use `.Split` but it doesn't exist.

Expected output:

```
SCOTT Bryan
SCOTT Bradley
SMITH Ava
WILLIAMS Olivia
```

Comment: How should the result look? You might want `.Select` or `.SelectMany`.

Comment: Please show the **exact** output you want.

Comment: Does your string array always contain names with the "FirstName LastName" format?

Comment: @SᴇM yes, it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the names in your string will always be the "first name" first then the "last name", then you can do something like this:

```
string[] result = fullNames.Select(s => s.Split(' '))
                           .Select(s => $"{s[1].ToUpper()} {s[0]}")
                           .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason split does not exist is because your string is an array.

So you may have to

```
string[] fullNames = new string[] { "Bryan Scott", "Bradley Scott", "Ava Smith", "Olivia Williams" };
string[] SingleName;
foreach (var item in fullNames)
{
    SingleName = item.Split(" ");
    // Write your logic here
}
```

Comment: Did you read the title. I'd like to use a lambda stream

Comment: This should work for you. var individualNames = fullNames.Select(a => a.Split(" "));